# QT Quick or C++ Checking for valid email input (email format validator)

Tags: c++, qt-quick

Please I am trying to write a code that checks whether a users input is a valid input or not in QT quick.

I want it to check and if it does not fulfill the usual email format not allow user to submit but notify him that the email is wrong.

I have seen samples for php and some c++ but from my experience, I cannot really work in qt quick the way I would when using Qt C++ line edit methods so was wondering if anyone has tried this out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this EMail validation javascript code

```
function validateForm(email)
{

  var atpos=email.indexOf("@");
  var dotpos=email.lastIndexOf(".");
  if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=email.length)
  {
    //Not a valid e-mail address
    return false;
  }
}
```

Read this to see how you can import javascript into QML

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qdeclarativejavascript.html#importing-one-javascript-file-from-another

Comment: This validator will accept several invalid email adresses. Also, it doesn't return anything on `success`, only on failure.